# Uncaught Cannot convert Array to Object[][] when passing array of arrays to range.setValues()

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

**Desired Behaviour**

Populate Google Sheet with array of arrays from a Javascript file.

```
// in js file (within google apps script project)   
var aoa = [["row_01_val01", "row_01_val02", "row_01_val03"],
           ["row_02_val01", "row_02_val02", "row_02_val03"]]; // etc
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(console.log("success")).populateSpreadsheet(aoa); 


// in code.gs
// define target_range (ignore discrepancies between example values above)
var target_range = active_sheet.getRange(2, 1, 834, 20); 

// set values of target_range
target_range.setValues(aoa);
```

**Current Behaviour**

```
// chrome developer tools (firefox/firebug not supported at work)  
Uncaught Cannot convert Array to Object[][]
```

**Question**

I'm unable to post more specific code due to work restrictions (cannot access SO from work, or take code home, hence the pseudo code), but are there any common `'gotchas'` when it comes to passing an array of arrays from a Javascript file to `Code.gs` for use in `setValues()`?

**What I've Tried**

In the js file, `console.log(typeof(aoa))` returns `object` just before passing it to `populateSpreadsheet()` within `Code.gs`, and then `Logger.log(aoa)` within `populateSpreadsheet()` also returns `object`

Example:

```
var outer_array = [];
inner_array = [1,2,3];
outer_array.push(inner_array);
typeof(outer_array);
"object"
```

I've tried to refactor the code several times, but am wondering if there are any common gotchas like size constraints, quotas, or timeouts or some other 'quirk' I haven't considered?

This question and answer, for example, required the array of arrays to be reconstructed before passing it to `setValues()` (I tried this but it didn't work in my instance):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066322/1063287

Another thing I considered is that I'm using `splice()`([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) to add some values to the inner array's within `Code.gs`, so I'm not sure if that somehow changes the type permissible to be passed to `setValues()`?

Comment: When you get the target range, it must be exactly the same dimensions as the two dimensional array.  First test the data in code.gs for it's data type with `typeof aoa`  For example: `if (typeof aoa !== 'object') {aoa = JSON.parse(aoa)}; //convert string to array`  Then get the range with `var target_range = active_sheet.getRange(2, 1, aoa.length, aoa[0].length); //set rows to number of inner arrays and columns to number of elements in first array`

Comment: Your suggestions assisted me think more clearly about the problem, it turns out I had a nested object within my inner arrays that I had forgotten about (the array and objects I was working with were large) and that was the issue - once I did some refactoring and made sure everything was an array value it worked well.