# pull MySQL table data to gsheet via JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I'm attempting to pull data from a mySQL table and populate it into a gsheet. I've written the following script, but I'm given an error at line 50 "Cannot convert array to Object". I'm certain this is a 2d array. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, though, as this is my very first script.

```
function readFromTable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetDetails = ss.getSheetByName('Details');
  var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var host = sheetDetails.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var databaseName = sheetDetails.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var userName = sheetDetails.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var password = sheetDetails.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var port = sheetDetails.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var tableName = sheetDetails.getRange("B6").getValue();

  var url = 'jdbc:mysql://'+host+':'+port+'/'+databaseName;
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName;
  try{

    var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password);

    var results = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    var metaData = results.getMetaData();
    var columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

    //Retrieve metaData to a 2D array
    var values = [];
    var value = [];
    var element = '';

    //Get table headers
    for(i = 1; i <=columns; i ++){
      element = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
      value.push(element);
    }
    values.push(element);

    //Get table data row by row
    while(results.next()){
      value = [];
      for(i = 1; i <= columns; i ++){
        element = results.getString(i)
        value.push(element);
      }
      values.push(value);
    }


    //Close connection
    results.close();

    //Write data to sheet Data
    sheetData.clear();
    sheetData.getRange(1, 1, values.length, value.length).setValues(values);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Your data has been refreshed');
  }catch(err){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the language/framework you are using (this looks like JavaScript, but I'm not certain about that).

Comment: Isn't JDBC for Java? Your code looks a lot like JavaScript. What libraries are you using? Please clear out the ambiguity.

Comment: You probably want to use PHP and create a `.csv` which can be used in almost any spreadsheet type.

Comment: @ndkhope I'm new so please forgive me for any lack details. Thought I provided a fair amount here... JDBC can be used in Google Apps Script to connect to an RDBMS, in my case MySQL. I've seen several others do this online.

Comment: @PHPglue we prefer to keep things in the Gsuite of products as we have many people accessing these files. We're also running other scripts within the gsheet to execute other tasks.

Comment: Maybe start with [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases)?

Comment: You can use this as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061470/from-array-to-setvalues-gives-cannot-convert-to